# Calling Service in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am just starting learning angular2.I have problem while calling service in angular2.The service calls successfully,but I have problem how can I handle data. In `Angular1` we do like this:

```
DemoService.getExchangeDataConnection().then(function(response){
//here we handle all the data
})
```

Angular2

```
constructor(private _sampleService: SampleService){
    this._sampleService = _sampleService;
}


 onClickMe(){
    this.clickMessage ='You are my hero!';
     this.error = "";
    this.countries = [];
    this._sampleService.test()
     .subscribe(
        data => this.countries = data,
        error => this.error = "Region " + this.region + " is invalid."
     );

  }
```

Here How can I handle data
Here is My service:

```
export class SampleService {

constructor(http: Http){
       this.http = http;
   }

   test(){
console.log(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT);
    return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT+"oceania").toPromise()
       .then(res => console.log(res.json()), err => console.log(err));
   }

}
```

Comment: Don't convert you http call to promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `test` method returns an observable you need to subscribe on it in a similar way than with promises:

```
this._sampleService.test()
   .subscribe(
     data => this.countries = data,
     error => this.error = "Region " + this.region + " is invalid."
   );
```

For example for a `test` method like this:

```
test() {
  return this.http.get('http://...').map(res => res.json());
}
```

You can notice that you can also use promises with Angular2. In this case, you will handle the response the same way as you did.

**Edit**

You could update your `test` method this way:

```
test(){
  console.log(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT);
  return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT+"oceania")
               .map(res => console.log(res.json());
 }
```

and call it like this:

```
this.service.test().subscribe(data => {
  (...)
});
```

If you want to leverage promise, you need to return something into your `then` callback to leverage chaining:

```
test(){
  console.log(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT);
  return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT+"oceania").toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json(), err => console.log(err)); // <---------
}
```

You can get your data now this way:

```
this.service.test().then(data => {
  (...)
});
```

Comment: I got subscribe is not a function

Comment: What does the `test` method return?

Comment: this returns the data,but I don't know how can I handle this

Comment: Could add the content of this method in your question? It will be easier to help you...